# Hive - time difference in minutes is negative

Tags: hadoop, hive, unix-timestamp

I need to get time difference in minutes for my analysis in Hive query.

I am using unix_timestamp() to convert dates to seconds and then subtracting to get the diff in seconds and the multiplied by 60 for minutes.

My issue is my recent date - older date difference is coming negative.

here is my query and results

[Hive query and result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9rPl.jpg)

`processed_ts   create_ts   processed_unix_timestamp    create_unix_timestamp   miniue Diff
2017-03-12 3:01:06  2017-03-12 2:58:36  1489312865  1489316315  -57.5
2017-03-12 3:01:36  2017-03-12 2:59:06  1489312895  1489316345  -57.5
2017-03-12 3:02:12  2017-03-12 2:59:42  1489312932  1489316382  -57.5`

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **USA & Canada Start DST on March 12**
> Published 17-Feb-2017
>
> Most of the United States, Canada, and Mexico's northern border cities
> will begin Daylight Saving Time (DST) on Sunday, March 12, 2017.
>
> People in areas that observe DST will spring forward 1 hour from 02:00
> (2 am) to 03:00 (3 am), local time.
> Standard time will resume on
> Sunday, November 5, 2017.
>
> https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/usa-canada-start-dst-2017.html

---

```
select timestamp '2017-03-12 02:58:36'
```

> 2017-03-12 0**3**:58:36